# How to enable buttons in MessageUI (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, xcode, imessage, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I'm trying to enable the Camera and Apps buttons in MessageUI for my app. I haven't found any place in Apple's documentation on how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: I found a `disableUserAttachments()` function in Apple's documentation, which is the opposite of what I'm looking for. Apple specifically says that this function disables the camera/attachment button in the message view. I don't have this code in my project and it's still disabled. I have not found something like enableUserAttachments which is what I think I need. Any ideas appreciated.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is 2020 and I think this problem still exists. I have been looking for a solution and thus far, I have found nothing. My understanding is that the camera button worked until iOS 10 and then it stopped. We're now up to iOS13 and the non-working button is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendAttachments() {

}
```

Refer this link below.
[developer.apple.com/messageui-sendattachments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller/1614076-cansendattachments)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem. Any ideas as to how to further troubleshoot this?